# Unable to click on a table cell to open the record

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I am trying to click on a on a cell in a row dynamically i.e. I pass the text present in the cell and trying to click on it.

Following is my code:

```
await element.all(by.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr')).then(rows => {
   rows.find(row => {
      return row.all(by.tagName('td')).filter(async elem => {
         await elem.getText().then(text => {
             return text === cellValue;
         });
      });
   }).click();
});
```

I expected this code to do the trick for me but it doesn't. I refrained from using those old for loops and then comparing one by one and then clicking assuming that these functions are much better.

The code above always clicks the first row and doesn't go inside

```
return row.all(by.tagName('td')).filter(async elem => {
```

There is no error thrown as well. Any idea what am I missing here.

**Update** - Following is working for me.

```
const rows = await element.all(by.xpath('//table/div/table/tbody/tr'));
        for (const row of rows) {
            const columns = await row.all(by.tagName('td'));
            const actualCellValue = await columns[columnIndex].getText();
            console.log(':::cell text:: ' + await columns[columnIndex].getText());
            if (actualCellValue === cellValue) {
                clickWhenAvailable(columns[columnIndex]);
                break;
            }
          }
        }
```

**Sample HTML Table Cell -**

```
<td _ngcontent-c30="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-Company mat-column-Company ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell"> VAX - ABC </td>
```

Comment: try returning `rows.find(row => {`

Comment: Can you put an id on the row that corresponds with the id of the data that was used to create the table? That way a simple `.find()` gets you the correct row. Or how do you know which text you are searching for? PS: .filter() returns an array, so if there always exactly one matching row, maybe the row is inside `.filter( ... your code ... )[0]`.

Comment: @DublinDev that doesn't work either, still clicking the first row.

Comment: @Shilly, shouldn't filter return only one record as there is this condition put in? As for id, I am not sure if I understood your point. I am searching for `cellValue`

Comment: @apun, no, `.filter()` returns a new array containing all the elements the callback returned true for. If multiple cells have the same text, you'll have multiple elements. Getting the first element a filter returns true for, is `.find()`. So `.find()` is basically `.filter()[0]`. (Unless this is not the native JS filter, but some kind of protractor function with the same name )

Comment: @Shilly, makes sense. What if I use find instead of filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Basically your code is failing because your first find is returning the **row** the contains the cell and not the cell element itself. That's probably why the click appears to always be in the first cell.

For some more detail there are a number of issues here so we can look at them in order.
You should not be using `await` with `.then`. Both of these are used to resolve promises so these two lines are equivalent

```
await element(by.css('button')).getText().then(btnText=> {
   console.log(btnText);
})

--- Is the same as (but below is much easier to read) ---

let btnText = await element(by.css('button')).getText();
console.log(btnText)
```

Next you are finding all `tr` element in the table and you are calling `.find` on this elementArray which contains row elements. `.find` finds one of the elements in the original array which are all row element in your case, it appears you are expecting a cell value.

It doesn't appear that you need to worry about the rows at all so you could try the following

```
await element(by.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr//td[text()=cellValue]').click();
```

Comment: Same result with the code sample you provided. Its clicking on the first record only.

Comment: Are you talking about the solution I posted first or the re-write of your original question? I realize I did not make that distinction clear, I'll correct it.

Comment: Also it seems like that cell contains the text to match the value of the variable `cellValue`. Is that the case?

Comment: I was talking about rewrite one. I won't mind trying what you suggested but just wondering as why this one is not working. Moreover, its a table with pagination, so not sure how well the suggestion would fit in. Yes, cellValue is the value of the cell text present in the table that I am passing and want to click.

Comment: Sorry I can see I made some pretty fundamental issues in my answer. I'm going to redo it

Comment: I've updated answer. I don't think pagination will be an issue but I could be overlooking something

Comment: `await element.all(by.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr//td[text()=cellValue]').click();` is not wotking and will never work as how will you find out the index of tr and td here? like it may be tr[2] or tr[4]. what do you say?

Comment: you are correct that is a typo. it should read `await element.(by.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr//td[text()=cellValue]').click();` there is no need for the `.all` as you only need to interact with one element.

Comment: You didn't get the point. It will never work. How will it find /tr[2] and all.

Comment: Why do you need to find `tr[2]`? Your question seems to indicate you want to find a cell with a particular text and click it. There should be no need to interact with the `tr` elements at all

Comment: What if the cell value is present in `await element(by.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[text()=cellValue]')`. Do you think your code will work? If I am correct, it will only work if there is a single cell and single row in the table.

Comment: Your understanding of how xpaths operate is incorrect. Xpaths work by looking for **any** matching element in a given structure, not just the first. It should find a matching cell whether the table has one row and cell or 10 rows and 20 cells. xpath`//tbody/tr/td` will return all cells, within all rows within all tbodys on the page.  `/` means look at only direct children and `//` means look at all descendants. It would be very worth while for you to spend some additional time looking into [how xpaths work](http://learnselenium.techcanvass.com/xpath-tutorial-in-selenium/)

Comment: I would encourage you to open up chrome dev tools and try find some elements manually yourself, it's the best way to learn. [In this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/SgvtXPh) you can see how you can identify some elements on a table on this stackoverflow page itself. Just open up dev tools and press control+F to being a search of the html.

Comment: Sure mate. Thanks for correcting me in that case. I will give it another try then because it didn't work for me yesterday. I wonder why people use rows and columns iterations as this sounds very crisp if it works. Lemme give it another try.

Comment: I don't know but it returns 0 elements found. Any thoughts? And xpath I gave is correct.

Comment: Also, I highlighted `await element.(by.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr/td'))`, it highlights only first cell of first row. And if what you said is correct, shouln't it highlight all the cells of all the rows? May be you can try at your end once.

Comment: The dev tools search will only highlight one at a time but you should see a indication on the right of the search box detailing how many total are found. I have that section highlighted in that screenshot. Not sure why the locator I provided is not returning any results, if you could include some of the table html in your answer it would greatly help us getting the correct result to you.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong. Tried on another website and it works. This greatly simplifies things in fact. I am copying a part of my html if you could see why it's not working. And thanks for correcting me, I was so wrong in my assumption. Also, thanks for the efforts to try help me out.

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure if it's just the formatting in you post but there are some additional whitespaces around the text in your cell so you can you try `await element(by.xpath('//div/table/tbody/tr//td[text()=" VAX - ABC "]').click();`